# generic function parameter giving "Expression type is ambiguous without more context"

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I have a function which takes two parameters related to RxSwift and bidirectionally bind them.

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa
func bibind<T>(property: ControlProperty<T>, variable: Variable<T>) -> Disposable {

    var updating = false

    let bindToUIDisposable = variable.asObservable().filter({ _ in
        updating = !updating
        return updating
    }).bind(to: property)
    let bindToVariable = property.filter({ _ in
        updating = !updating
        return updating
    }).subscribe(onNext: { n in
        variable.value = n
    }, onCompleted:  {
        bindToUIDisposable.dispose()
    })

    return CompositeDisposable(bindToUIDisposable, bindToVariable)
}
```

I am trying to call it like this

```
bibind(property: self.userNameTextField.rx.text, variable: self.loginViewModel.userName.value )
```

Which is showing compiler error

```
Expression type 'Variable<String>' is ambiguous without more context
```

The view model is this

```
import Foundation
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class LoginViewModel {
    var userName = Variable<String>("")
    var password = Variable<String>("")

    init() {
        userName = Variable("")
        password = Variable("")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The types don't match. `userNameTextField.rx.text` returns an `Observable<String?>` and your variable is an `Observable<String>`. You can fix this by using `orEmpty` as in `userNameTextField.rx.text.orEmpty`.

In general, when you see this error, it means the types don't match and you need to fix it by changing the type of one of the objects.

Comment: Thanks! You made my day!

Comment: This saved my day, My problem was similar, because I have set a type to String, but was giving a String?